# How to make columns names, and data in lane - data not i table but in list

Tags: sql, output, line, sqlplus, separator

When I run following statements in SQLPlus

```
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET LINESIZE 250
SET NUMWIDTH 5
SET FEEDBACK OFF
set echo off
set heading on
set headsep off
set wrap off
SET COLSEP ";"

SPOOL clients.csv

SELECT id, name, age FROM clients;
```

I'v got something like that:

```
id;name;age
1;Alex;22
2;Adam;36
3;Cody;27
```

but is it possible, to got output like that:

```
id;name;age;1;Alex;22;2;Adam;36;3;Cody;27
```

So I just want all value separated by ';' even col names, i want something like "don't use **ENTER** when you got all columns, but put **";"** instead".

Comment: Welcome! Why do you need that? For what purpose?

Comment: Take a look at this on StackExchange [How to make sqlplus output appear in one line?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54149/how-to-make-sqlplus-output-appear-in-one-line).